# Passing a variable from STT to url gets separated in Python

Tags: python

#### Project

I am trying to create a smart voice recognizer with Python. I use [SpeechRecognition](https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/) as my Library for performing speech recognition. So far so good. I also want to include a weather API functionality that looks up the weather condition from a specific location.

#### Problem

I capture the location as a variable through SpeechRecognition. Then I want to use that variable inside my URL like so:

```
        elif 'weer in' in command:
            apikey = 'key'
            location = command.replace('weer in', '')
            print location
            # using the string format method
            apiurl = 'http://website/api/json-data.php?key={apikey}&locatie={location}'.format(apikey=apikey, location=location)
            print(apiurl)
```

**Output:**

```
weer in amsterdam
 amsterdam
http://website.nl/api/json-data.php?key=key&locatie= amsterdam
```

As you can see, de location variable is separated from the URL.
I know it has probably to do with SpeechRecognition conversion, so I've tried to convert the variable to a string (which SpeechRecognition should do by itself) but that ain't working as well.

#### What I've tried

- String concatenation :
  `apiurl = 'http://website.nl/api/json-data.php?key='+apikey+'&locatie='+teststring`
- String parameters : `apiurl = 'http://website.nl/api/json-data.php?key=%s&locatie=%s' % (apikey, location)`
- f' string : `apiurl = f'http://website.nl/api/json-data.php?key={apikey}&locatie={location}'`
- Format string : `apiurl = 'http://webiste.nl/api/json-data.php?key={apikey}&locatie={location}'.format(apikey=apikey, location=location)`

Comment: There's an extra space `' '` left in the string after you do `command.replace`. You can just `rstrip()` the `location` to get rid of it.

Comment: @rdas Indeed, although rstrip() did not work, strip() did. Like so : `location = command.replace('weer in', '').strip()` Thanks!